# What does bearer stand for?

Tags: jwt, bearer-token

In context of jwt tokens the word bearer ist used. I cannot find a lot about bearer on Google. I was wondering where the terms comes from and what it stand for? And why is it prefixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why is it prefixed?

Because otherwise it would just be a bunch of random characters with no context whatsoever, other than knowing that it's some info for some type of authorization.

> what it stand for?

That the one who bears the token has the authority to do whatever the token allows

> where the terms comes from

Hopefully Lord of The Rings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring#Ring-bearers) but I doubt it ;) It's a standard English-language word

Answer (score 1):

A "bearer" is simply "a person or thing that carries, upholds, or brings", according to dictionary.com. So, in the context of JWT (or SAML, etc.) tokens, the "bearer" is simply the person or entity that presents the token to the server or resource.

Comment: But why is prefixed before the token?

Comment: It's a token that's expected to be presented by the bearer. Same sense as "bearer bonds" (cf Die Hard, 1988)